# Descending List From N to 1

Tags: recursion, prolog

I'm trying to make a predicate desclist(N,L) (N is a natural number and L is a list of natural numbers in descending order from N to 1). Also i can't use is/2, metalogic predicates, negation, fails, cuts, etc... Just pure logical programming. i'm a little lost about how to make it.
i tried with:

```
desclist(s(0),[s(0)]).
desclist(nat(X),[]).
desclist(0,[]).
desclist(X,[X|[R1|R2]]):- desclist(R1,[R1|R2]).
```

but, as you can see, its a complete disaster without any sense at all hahah... please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `N` is a natural number, then `s(N)` is its successor. Conversely, if `s(N)` is a natural number greater than 0, then `N` is its predecessor. Since the recursive call must be done with a smaller instance of the problem being solved, you can do:

```
desclist(0, []). % base case
desclist(s(N), [s(N)|L]) :- desclist(N, L). % step case
```

Examples:

```
?- desclist(s(s(s(0))), L).
L = [s(s(s(0))), s(s(0)), s(0)].

?- desclist(N, [s(s(s(s(0)))), s(s(s(0))), s(s(0)), s(0)]).
N = s(s(s(s(0)))).
```